# total items not get in response sendgrid nodejs Api

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

## Retrieve all recipients on a List:-

```
`var request = sg.emptyRequest()
  request.queryParams["page"] = '1'
  request.queryParams["page_size"] = '1'
  request.queryParams["list_id"] = '1'
  request.method = 'GET'
  request.path = '/v3/contactdb/lists/{list_id}/recipients'
  sg.API(request, function (error, response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode)
    console.log(response.body)
    console.log(response.headers)
  });`
```

here is my Api Response:-

```
 `{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": {
    "recipients": [
      {
        "created_at": 1486990474,
        "email": "jones2@example.com",
        "first_name": null,
        "id": "am9uZXMyQGV4YW1wbGUuY29t",
        "last_clicked": null,
        "last_emailed": null,
        "last_name": "tyutyut",
        "last_opened": null,
        "updated_at": 1486990474
      }
    ]
  },
  "headers": {
    "server": "nginx",
    "date": "Mon, 20 Feb 2017 07:11:31 GMT",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "content-length": "1052",
    "connection": "close",
    "access-control-allow-methods": "HEAD, GET, PUT, POST, DELETE,OPTIONS,PATCH",
    "access-control-max-age": "21600",
    "access-control-expose-headers": "Link",
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000",
    "x-ratelimit-remaining": "0",
    "x-ratelimit-limit": "1",
    "x-ratelimit-reset": "1487574692",
    "powered-by": "Mako"
  }
}`
```

> i am calling reciepents list by list id.
> pagination is working in this Api but i am not getting total items params in response.

Comment: I have gone through the API, but didn't find anything like total items, what response you are getting from that API call?

Comment: see response in my question

Comment: since you did not get total Items,you can count it manually by yourself using,  `response.body.recipients.length` gives you total items

Comment: then i will have to get all listing and manage pagination on my side. this is not a proper solution

Comment: ok, I think you can call `request.path = '/v3/contactdb/lists/{list_id}/recipients/count'` seperately to get the count of the records., source https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/USAGE.md

Comment: i have tried it is not working. count option is only available for all recipients Api

Answer (score 1):

SendGrid, sadly, doesn't seem to provide the count of recipients in the API you are using. However they offer a separate API call from which you can get the total count of recipients:

> GET /v3/contactdb/lists/{list_id}

For example:

```
var request = sg.emptyRequest();

request.queryParams["list_id"] = '1';
request.method = 'GET';
request.path = '/v3/contactdb/lists/{list_id}';

sg.API(request, function(error, response) {
  console.log(response.statusCode);
  console.log(response.body);
  console.log(response.body.id); // The list id
  console.log(response.body.name); // The list name
  console.log(response.body.recipient_count); // The count of all recipients of this list
  console.log(response.headers);
});
```